# Audio won't play in iOS Cordova Phonegap app

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, audio

I am creating a cross platform Cordova Phonegap soundboard app. Everything works fine on the android version but on the iOS version the sound refuses to play. I use SoundJS and PreloadJS to load and play the audio. I used the Phonegap remote debugging server and found out that iOS recognizes the audio as something called "application/octet stream" (see pictures).

Everything is fine on Android

[Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b38tG.jpg)

But I get this on iOS

[iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHZP0.jpg)

I load the audio like this:

```
var sound3= "sound3";
    createjs.Sound.registerSound("audio/anybody.mp3", sound3);

    $(function(){
    $( "#sound3" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler ) 

    function tapHandler( event ){

        sound3.play();
    }
});
```

Can somebody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue on one of my Cordova projects.

First possible reason:

This appears because of different browsers(web views) can play just some specific types. You need to have sound in different formats, such as `mp3` or `ogg` and before playing sound you need to detect maintained format. Look at this documentation [Audio canPlayType](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_canplaytype.asp) and make checks before playing

Second possible reason : 
[File system](http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/cant_play_audio_files_on_ios_but_they_work_on_android) issues. `iOS` resources path is not equal to `Android` resources path and before sound initialization you need to build a platform-specific path to your local resources

And also try to play native browser `audio` instead of using `createjs`, like this:

```
var sound3 = document.createElement('audio');

sound3.src = "audio/anybody.mp3";

function tapHandler( event ){
    sound3.play();
}

$(function(){
  $( "#sound3" ).bind( "tap", tapHandler ) 
});
```

Comment: I didn't specify alternative file types but I did try with wav, mp3 and ogg and none of them worked. How do I find out the iOS path to my local resources?

Comment: I'm having a file system issues and the given link is broken. Anybody have an updated link or an explanation of how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using an m4a audio file (aac)? This seems to be the format Apple prefers. Also make sure there is always only one sound playing at the time as iOS can only handle one audio playback at a time.

Comment: m4a doesn't work on ios either. Still getting the error `(NATIVE AUDIO) Asset reference does not exist. (assets/sounds/roll0.m4a)`